# How to access specific parts of strings java?

Tags: java

I have to write a simulator that reads lines of strings that are all formatted the exact same. They look like this "Add Job_A with length 10", where the only thing changing is the second word and the number at the end. How to a access and save the Job_A and 10 and as variables. I can't count through the string letters because the job could have a different length name, and the integer could have a different amount of digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions, for example:

```
String input = "Add Job_A with length 10";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Add (.+) with length (\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

if (matcher.matches()) {
    // Input has correct format, we can extract matched values into variables
    String jobName = matcher.group(1);
    int number = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
} else {
    // Input has incorrect format
}
```